# Hide small images on frontend Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-images, media-images

I have **Magento 2** and want to hide small images of the product that is added from the **admin** on **frontend**. I have hidden the small image attribute from admin but want to hide it from front-end as well.

Comment: you can try simple css trick to hide

Comment: Can you please tell how @Manoj Deswal

Comment: you can try with code as well , check solution and let me know if any problem , i just checked it on luma based theme and it works

Comment: Your code seems to be working but not as I want. It has hidden all the thumbnails.

Comment: oh I mistaken , could you please share some screenshots...so that will easy to know the right question

Comment: Yes sure,
http://prntscr.com/iyf6k3
http://prntscr.com/iyf73u

Comment: @A.Srivastava, please find the below solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/233478/52244, if you fine with this or it match your expection please mark as a valid answer so in future other can use. thanks :)

Comment: @A.Srivastava do you find the sollution

Answer (score 11):

You can try with either CODE or CSS

**1) Changing / Adding code in your extended `view.xml`**

Can find at below path or if not present then you can create

> app/design/frontend/vendor-name/theme-name/etc/view.xml

Add below code

```
<vars module="Magento_Catalog">
    <var name="gallery">
        <var name="nav">false</var> <!-- Gallery navigation style (false/thumbs/dots) -->
    </var>
</vars>
```

Keep your cache disable or clear your cache

**2) Using CSS in you custom style sheet**

```
.fotorama__nav{display:none;}
```

Perform whatever things you do for using custom CSS to work

I hope this will get you desired solution

Comment: Sorry, But i think you did not completely get my point. 
When we add the image from admin then we have the various image attributes like Small, Base, Thumbnail etc.
I want to hide the images that has "Small" as an attribute on product view page.

Comment: @A.Srivastava do you get the sollutionn to hide small selected images from frontend ?

Answer (score 8):

In admin panel product level,

when you are uploading the image and setting role as **small** in the same time choose **Hide from Product Page** checkbox as well.

then flush the cache and see result you will get your expected output (Your will not get small image in product detail page).

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Seems broken either in 2.3.2 or some extension broke it.